# Prepend string to line if line ends in keyword

Tags: regex, string, awk, prepend

Assume a multi-line text file (`file`) and the keyword `bar`.

```
> cat file
foo bar baz
foo bar quux
foo quux bar
```

Each line that ends with the keyword shall be prepended with the string `Hello`; each line that does not shall be printed as is.

```
> cat file | sought_command
foo bar baz
foo bar quux
Hello foo quux bar
```

I believe that this can be done via `awk` (something along the lines of `awk '$ ~ /bar/ {print "Hello", $0}'`), but I cannot come up with the correct code and would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Are the words tab separated or space separated?

Comment: @Inian The words are space-separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *almost* on the right track using `Awk`, just use the regex anchor `$` to mark the end the line, and append the string as needed,

```
awk '$NF == "bar"{$0="Hello"FS$0}1' file
```

This will append string *only* to those lines having keyword in the last.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '/bar$/{$0 = "Hello" FS $0} 1' file

foo bar baz
foo bar quux
Hello foo quux bar
```

This will check if a line ends with `bar` and if it does then it will prefix that line with string `"Hello "`.

If line doesn't end with `bar` then that line will be printed as is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply too. Basically same answer as above.

Comment: How would I add a linebreak before the string _Hello_? The command `awk '/bar$/{$0 = $0 "\nHello" FS $0} 1' file` does not generate such a linebreak, and I am uncertain why not.

Comment: That works for me and inserts a line break before `Hello`

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed 's/.* bar$/Hello &/' infile
foo bar baz
foo bar quux
Hello foo quux bar
```

The space before `bar` makes sure to not match lines ending in `foobar`; it would break for lines containing `bar` and nothing else, though.

With awk, if you want to match only `foo` and not `foobar`:

```
$ awk '$NF == "bar" { $0 = "Hello " $0 }1' infile
foo bar baz
foo bar quux
Hello foo quux bar
```